# Recycling UIViews with UIImageViews in them - old images appear

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I'm recycling UIViews which have UIImageViews in them. So when one of these is re-used, the first thing I have to do is clear out the old image it was displaying. I can't seem to get this to work. My current code is:

```
[self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
self.imageView = nil;
```

And then I'm re-alloc/init-ing the `UIImageView`, `UIImage` and so on. This doesn't seem to do the trick. The old image appears, then the new image appears on top of it. What else do I need to do to clear out the old image?

Thanks.

Comment: If you aren't using ARC try releasing them and maybe check the retain count.

Comment: I am using ARC. I thought when using ARC, if I set a pointer to nil it automatically releases that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deallocating your UIImageView, you're kind of losing a lot of the benefit of recycling your views, since you're just rebuilding them.

When you recycle your UIView, make sure to nil the **image** property of the UIImageView - that way, you are not retaining the UIImage while your UIView is in a recycled state - no point in doing that.

When you pull your UIView out of recycling to reuse it, the image should have been cleared out and you can reset the **image** property of the UIImageView with the new image data.  You should see the new image at that point.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIView`'s `CALayer` presentation model probably is dirty. Try:

```
[self setNeedsDisplay]; //force refresh
```